# Python2: Unable to write current time to file

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import time
from time import time, sleep

end_time = time() + 3 * 3600
while time() < end_time:
    with open('mytime.txt', 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
        sleep(60)
```

I am unable to print the current time to a file. My code leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mytime.py", line 58, in <module>
    the_file.write(time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

But this code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import time
print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
```

However, it only prints the time and does not save it to a file.

Where is the difference, what do I make wrong in the first example?

Comment: Because you're importing time and from time you're importing time. So you'll end up with having only the time module from time package in the python scope. A fix, is just importing time then using time.time(), time.sleep() and time.strftime()

Comment: @ChihebNexus: Thanks a lot, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example you have:

```
from time import time
```

That means, if you call  `time.strftime(...)`, you tell Python to call strftime from object `time` from module `time`. Because you imported only object `time` from module `time`, not entire module. And the object `time` is a function.

In the second example you import properly whole module:

```
import time
```